# SQL 2005 Deadlocks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, deadlock

In an asp.net application that I work on I wrote the data access layer with try - catch on every call to the database and in the catch phrase i log any errors that occur. I also write most of the stored procedure code and all the select statements are using the nolock hint. Some of these select statements are getting numerous but not always deadlock errors like the following "Transaction (Process ID 86) was deadlocked on lock resources **with another process** and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction." I need to know a process to discover what **other process** is that the error message is referring to. Any help appreciated - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your DBA to turn on DBCC TRACESTATUS (1222, -1). This will give you information in the sql server error log. Please see link below.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2130/finding-sql-server-deadlocks-using-trace-flag-1222/

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend to go through the Deadlock article on SqlServer-Online documentation. You can detect the deadlocks on SqlServer itself, if you have DBA please work with them.

The below article is handful, it recommends how to detect, solve & avoid deadlocks.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177433(v=sql.105).aspx